# how to get mod_ldap authenticated user information in java

Tags: java, apache, ibmhttpserver, mod-ldap

My httpd.conf in IHS looks like this

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication for Billing"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL ldaps://xxx.com/ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com?mail,cn,dept 
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthGroupFile conf/groups.txt
Require group Admin
```

Now as per Apache documentation I am expecting values in environment variables :
    System.getenv("AUTHENTICATE_CN"),
    System.getenv("AUTHENTICATE_MAIL")
    System.getenv("AUTHENTICATE_DEPT")

but all I get is NULL. I am only getting the authenticated email id in request.getRemoteUser(). I also tried System.getProperties(), but nothing there also. Please let me know how I can get the other informations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal Apache environment variables aren't shared or otherwise conveyed from the webserver to the application server. But you could copy them into request headers with e.g.

```
RequestHeader set AUTHENTICATE_CN %{AUTHENTICATE_CN}e
```

Which you'd access like any other request header on the application server.